# Chrome extension performance

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension. The extension itself works fine and fast.

But when I start the browser and click on the toolbar icon of my extension it takes about 2 seconds for the popup to appear and to show its content (this happens anytime the browser is restarted).

Any idea what causes this and how to fix that?

Comment: This happens with a lot of extensions actually, LastPass in particular seems to take an age to display the menu.

Comment: What do you have in the popup?

Comment: well, a lot. a tab view with 4 tabs, I am accessing local storage too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tip 1:

Use your popup page for rendering exclusively. It should be as light as possible. All the heavy loading/processing (localStorage, XMLHttpRequests, blocking javascript) must be done in the [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html).

The background page is loaded when Google Chrome starts. Basically, it allows you to execute code and keep a page always running (although the popup is not present). For instance, streaming audio in a html5  tag with no popup.

Note: If you are not using a background page yet, you should be taking a look to message passing first.

---

Tip 2: **Warning: This could fail**

I haven't tested this yet, but maybe using the HTML5 **[manifest.cache](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Application-Caching/)** can help you preventing loading again resources stored locally. But beware, this is HTML5 and is prone to changes and unstability across versions. (also, I am not completely sure that the cached resources will be loaded in memory before the popup is opened)

Hope it helps!